# Xskak/Chessboard moverstyle squarearrow

Tags: chessboard, xskak

I am trying to use moverstyle=squarearrow on Xskak/chessboard. code is like this :

```
\usepackage{pifont,graphicx}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\usepackage{texmate}

\newchesgame
\chessboard{moverstyle=squarearrow}
```

It works if i keep texmate, removing texmate it throw an error "undefined control sequence" and show only the arrow.

[image: This is the result with/without texmate]

Comment: Show a small but complete example. That makes it much easier to test.

Answer (score 1):

The undefined command is `\square`. This command is provided by the `amssymb` package, which is loaded by `texmate`. You can also load it yourself:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont,graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\chessboard[moverstyle=squarearrow]
\end{document}
```

Note that `chessboard` itself (i.e., Ulrike Fischer) made the decision not to load `amssymb`, as explained in the changelog in the manual:

> 2011-03-17 (Version 1.7) Changed definition of the triangle mover
> style. It now uses tikz and no longer amssymb. chessboard no longer
> loads amssymb (it clashes with xunicode).

So apparently there could be some incompatibilities - but the MWE above works ok and produces the same output as your first picture.

Comment: hm, somebody should notify the maintainer ;-)

Comment: So to avoid incompatibilities is better not use amssymb ? and pick another moverstyle ?

Comment: @NicoLopez it is probably safe to use `amssymb`. You can just write your document with this moverstyle, and only change it if you actually encounter an incompatibility. Possibly Ulrike will update the package in the mean time to fix the problem completely, which would mean that you can use your original code without errors.